# If we take out the kernel, what is left of the OS?

Tags: linux

The following are some of the tasks that a kernel is responsible for:

- Launching a program (creating a process)
- Handling interrupts
- Context switching
- Protect the processes from interfering with each other (by using
  virtual memory)
- Inter-process communication mechanisms
- Accessing IO devices
- etc.

If the above is what a kernel is responsible for, then what is left to the OS? I mean the only thing that is left that I can think of are the application software (for example: bash, ls, gedit, Firefox, etc.).

But can we really consider application software to be part of the OS? and if we can, then is it only the application software that comes with the OS that are considered part of the OS? what if we installed an application software later, will that application software not be considered part of the OS?

Answer (score 1):

> "To explain what Linux is, you have to explain what an operating
>   system is. And think about an operating system, I mean, you’re
>   never-ever supposed to see it; because nobody really uses an operating
>   system; people use programs on their computers and the only mission in
>   life for an operating system is to help those programs run. So, an
>   operating system never does anything on its own, it’s only waiting for
>   the programs to ask for certain resources or ask for certain files on
>   the disk, or ask for programs to connect them to the outside world.
>   And then the operating system steps in and tries to make it easy for people to write programs."

Linus Torvalds, in *Revolution OS*

And he's right - people use Applications, not operating systems.  Was able to switch back and forth between OS X and Linux on the desktop fairly painlessly once I learned how do deal with the OS X Desktop and opening/closing applications.  Firefox, Chrome, and a bash shell don't change much....

One of the reasons I've been able to switch many non-technical users to Linux.  Install a nice desktop (I like Mint w/ MATE) so it looks somewhat familiar (menu button ,etc) set up the favorites so they can get to Chrome/Firefox, Thunderbird if needed, a calculator, OpenOffice, etc. and they are as happy as a clam, never knowing or caring about having Linux and not Windows, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## The shell, of course.

[Remember the nut metaphor](https://superuser.com/a/329479/38062), and remember that it *is* a metaphor.